# Firebase Analytics for multiple apps

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am building a Application which is personal for each user, i.e a service from which users can build and generate new Android application for themselves. I was wondering if we can user single Firebase Analytic's/ Google analytic's for multiple applications(each with separate ApplicationID). Just like we can do this on Admob, though I know from prior experience its a bad idea to use same admob integration on multiple applications. This does sound a wired use case, but I wish to track which application(user created custom app) has been downloaded most and it is being used.

Answer (score -2):

Each user's app should be registered individually on the Firebase console. And each app will receive its own distinct app id (in the form of a JSON or .plist file) and that will ensure that the analytics for each app is separate.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, Is their any other Analytics tool for mobile where I can use a single console to monitor 100's of applications each all with different Application ID.

Comment: Google Analytics should be able to support this.